# Does LEGO no longer support NXT 2.0 at all?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, nxt, software, mac

I am running Mac OS X 10.15 (Catalina) and the EV3 software can't detect my NXT 2.0 using USB.

Comment: Is there any new on this issue - and is there any way to do graphical / scratch programming on NXT bricks with Mac OS Big Sur og Windows 10.

Answer (score 7):

LEGO officially stopped supporting NXT in 2015, however, as of 2019, the original NXT programming software is still available on the official LEGO MINDSTORMS web page.

The original NXT programming software and EV3 desktop programming software are both 32-bit, so cannot run on macOS 10.15 or later.

The new EV3 programming software based on Scratch does not work with NXT. So the only way to program NXT on macOS 10.15 is with 3rd party software such as [NXC/NQC](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/) or [leJOS](http://www.lejos.org/nxj.php) or by installing a macOS or Windows virtual machine to run the old desktop software.

Answer (score 5):

The NXT is no longer for sale by Lego, and I don't think they offer technical support for the NXT platform anymore. However, the EV3 software [does support NXT](https://education.lego.com/en-au/support/mindstorms-ev3/nxt-compatibility). If you can't connect the software to the brick, it might be a driver issue. You can download the official NXT "Fantom" driver from the [downloads page of the Mindstorms website](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads) - just scroll down until you see the "NXT Software Download" section. Alternatively, you could just download and install the full NXT 2.0 software package from that same source - that's probably your best bet to get things working.

Answer (score 1):

`EV3 Classroom` is supposed to work with the NXT brick.

https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software

Comment: NXT ultrasonic sensor is NOT recognised by EV3 Classroom, apparently? I can only use EV3 ultrasonic sensors :-(